Getting last days prices on iLow(NULL,PERIOD_H1,0)
i have an expert advisor that runs on daily timeframe, in it i need to get a few candles low prices. candles are from 1 to 7; when i use iLow(NULL,,PERIOD_H1,0) till iLow(NULL,,PERIOD_H1,7) i get exactly 0 till 7 low prices but for yesterday! why is it?
tradeTime=D'08:00:00';
void OnTick()
  {     
    if (TimeHour(currentTime) == TimeHour(tradeTime) && TimeMinute(currentTime) == TimeMinute(tradeTime) && tradeFlag==1) 
    {
    
          for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            double low = iLow(NULL, PERIOD_H1, i);
            Print(low);
        }
    }
}

i have tried to run it in different times (instead of 8) sometimes it works and sometimes not!

share full code or make it MCVE. what is currentTime? Most likely you start testing at different time (your time at terminal) versus tradeTime - if you start at 8h, 9h or 7h (today) when it's 8am at your terminal

Your tags are MQL4 and MQL5, which is it? They are two very different languages!


iLow(NULL, PERIOD_H1, 0) = Will give you Low price of current candle
at H1_TimeFrame. Current candle is under formation
iLow(NULL, PERIOD_H1, 1) = Will give you Low price of previous candle at
H1_TimeFrame.
iLow(NULL, PERIOD_H1, 2) = Will give you Low price of
previous candle at shift 2 at H1_TimeFrame.
....

So your code is returning Low price at 1 Hour timeframe of last 7 candles. It could be possible that last 7 candles are formed within today or Yesterday. If you have candles of today on the chart, then code will return Low price of Todays candles or yesterdays.
Also make sure that you are running this EA on correct timeframe.
If you want to obtain Low price on current timeframe then use iLow(NULL, PERIOD_D1, i);

